# What interfaces besides MS Access are available to manipulate MDB files

Tags: microsoft-access, jetsql

A few years ago I was developing a .NET application for a client that used Microsoft Access. Regardless of the merits of this technical decision, I ended up writing [my own query editor](http://plane-disaster.sourceforge.net/) for [Microsft Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access) and [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) files.

I have since found out I was not the only one to do so.

Please, one program per answer.

Comment: Are you trying to ask a question or promote your own software ?

Comment: Bruce,

Actually, I'd like to use something else now that I know better things exist. Unfortunately, there seems to be a lack of interest in a propry SQL editor for MS Access.

That being said, I want this list to be as exhaustive as possible, and therefor it includes my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oracle SQL developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) works as well. It also connects to Oracle, MySql (no surprises) SQL Server, Sybase and DB2. See [Database Connections](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/featurelist-094691.html#con) on the feature list

Comment: I think I have a new favorite

Answer (score 1):

[PlaneDisaster.NET](http://plane-disaster.sourceforge.net/) Is the program I wrote to accomplish this task. The user interface leaves a lot to be desired, but it got the job done.

Comment: i like your naming convention :)

Answer (score 1):

[JetSQL Console](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jetsqlconsole/) is an open source command line only console app. Its written in QT, despite having no GUI. Its not very polished, but lets you manipulate MDB files via the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes another open source gui app for doing this is [MS Access Databases Queries Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/QueryEditor.aspx). It has a better looking GUI than PlaneDisaster.NET.

Comment: Marking this program as best of breed for now. If someone knows of a better program, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use [AnySQL Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/anysql/maestro/). The free version targes anything with an OLEDB driver.

Similarly you can use free JDBC tools + ODBC drivers to target MS-Access (as a generic JDBC/ODBC) database, although I haven't tried this for a long time so I'm not sure what exists now-a-days.

Comment: I will check out Maestro.

Answer (score 0):

[MDBPlus](http://www.alexnolan.net/software/mdb_viewer_plus.htm) works well and is able to open & edit very old Access databases.